How can I enforce naming conventions on spring rest controllers?
For our REST API we have standardized on using hyphen case,
i.e. GET /store-users?first-name=dan  and not GET /storeUsers?firstName=dan
How can we enforce this naming convention as developers keep adding non compliant URLs to the application.  Some static analysis of the spring rest controller annotations that would fail the maven build would be ideal.

Maybe you can create a custom rule in Checkstyle (or any other static code analysis tools) to validate that all @RequestMapping annotations follow the hyphen case naming convention. You can then integrate these tools with your Maven build, so the build fails if any non-compliant URLs are found.

You can use this post from the SonarQube community to get started: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/obtaining-arguments-and-values-inside-a-spring-boot-annotation/41855. It is also doing the same thing as you, checking the values of a RequestMapping annotation. Then, you just need to implement your logic to check for your coding style of choice

A Simple Unit Test should do:
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Test
public void allEndpointsShouldBeKebabCase() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);
    var methodMap = requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
    //Insert your endpoint path checks here
}


How does this answer OP‘s question?

I don't think this is what OP was looking for. As far as I can tell, they wanted to preemptively reject bad endpoints, not test for them after the fact.

@Jens
By default maven surefire will fail the build if there are failed Unit tests. I believe this is what OP is looking for.

Yes failing the build is the main thing, a failing build will prevent a code merge to master.  The only problem is creating an application context in a unit test that will load all Rest Controllers is not a simple task, as you have to mock out all dependencies.  Might be worth it though

you have at least 3 options:

in tests let spring create your context, get all the generated urls, assert them, fail the test if assertion fails (something like user @vuongdt23 suggested)

use ArchUnit and scan your classes, annotations, assert them, fail the test

create custom plugin / checks for static analysis tool (sonar? checkstyle?) and plug it into your CI/CD pipeline


imho, doing it in tests instead of external static analyis tool would be the easiest way
